# Can we consider Indian Astrology as astronomy?

Tags: discussion

Indian Astrology has mentioned about the basics of modern astrology. Apart from Varaha Samhita any other texts available on Indian Astrology/ Jyotish?

Comment: It is worth noting, the StackExchange for Hinduism has a tag for astrology.

Answer (score 10):

The point of astrology is making predictions about human affairs from the positions of celestial bodies. This is pseudoscience: there is no empirically observed pattern (if we leave out the weather and climate effects of the sun and tides) and people usually just assign traditional interpretations. However, motivated by astrology people have been doing meticulous observations and improved observation methods for a long time: this is a systematic search for knowledge, science. So, yes, there are parts of astronomy inside ancient astrology. Fortunately they got out.

Comment: Quite similar situation seen in transitioning from alchemy to chemistry, perhaps.

Answer (score 6):

We have ruled in this community that astrology of any sort, despite its historical entanglement with astronomy, is off-topic because of the pseudoscience mentioned by Anders. That said, if the questions are motivated by astrological sources but concern only astronomical phenomena, then they are on topic. Also, we have allowed questions about devices (such as symbols) that are in use in astronomy where the answer lies in the history of astrology.

Answer (score 2):

While it is probably not very clearly stated, the site is mostly about mainstream science, i.e. mainstream science of the today. But in my opinion, that part what could be considered a rudimentary form of the astronomy of the today, I think it might be okay (for example: "Indian astronomists in b.c. <big number> observed ..., could it have been a supernova?").

Note, the distinction between science and religion exists only some hundred years ago, and only in our civilization. The people of the ancient times did not consider them "astronomists with religion X (here hinduism)". On this reason, the part what is today considered science, is on-topic on https://hsm.stackexchange.com (History of Science and Math), because this site deals better not only the historical knowledge, but also with the world-view of the people at the time.

The part what is not science today, might be on-topic on https://hinduism.stackexchange.com and or on https://mythology.stackexchange.com .

The part of what is considered "astrology" today, is probably off-topic network-wide.